# How to read data from an XMLSocket in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

While using Socket, I am able to read the data as

```
while (socket.bytesAvailable) 
{
    textArea.text += socket.readUTFBytes(socket.bytesAvailable);
}
```

How can I read the data while using an `XMLSocket`? Is it enough to use `xmlSocket.toString()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, with XMLSocket receiving data is event driven, you create a socket, set up event handlers:

```
socket = new XMLSocket();   
socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler, false, 0, true);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler, false, 0, true);
socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler, false, 0, true);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler, false, 0, true);
socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityHandler, false, 0, true);    

socket.connect(host, port);
```

you will receive data in dataHandler:

```
private function dataHandler(e: DataEvent): void {  
   var xml: XML = XML(e.data);
   ...
}
```

Now you can process XML using whatever means you want. Sending is easier, but still you have to take into account that you are not connectd immediately after calling connect, you have to wait until connectHandler gets called before sending data:

```
var xml: XML = ...
if (socket.connected) {
  socket.send(xml);
}
```

Comment: There is no ProgressEvent.PROGRESS for XMLSocket.

Comment: That might indeed be true, in which case Adobe's own docs are inconsistent in that regard, see here: [XMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Comment: I left a comment there too ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onData);

private function onData(event:DataEvent):void {
    trace(event.data);
}
```